# Is -1 true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this test in a JavaScript file:

```
if (grouping.conditional(user)) {
    console.log(grouping.conditional(user));
}
```

`grouping.conditional` looks like this:

```
conditional: function(user) {
    if (user.apilog[0].referer) {
        return user.apilog[0].referer.indexOf('.google.')
    } 
    else {
        return false
}
```

For some reason, it outputs `-1` in some instances, isn't `-1` `false` in JavaScript? In that case, how come `if (grouping.conditional(user))` returns `true`?

Comment: Because indeed `-1` is not falsy in JavaScript.

Comment: `false` values are `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `false`, and `NaN`

Comment: `Boolean(-1) === true` http://es5.github.io/#x9.2

Comment: Consider: `!!-1 -> true`

Comment: Change it to `return user.apilog[0].referer.indexOf('.google.') > -1` if you only want to return true or false.

Answer (score 6):

The following values are *falsy* in JavaScript

```
false, 0, null, undefined, "", NaN
```

Everything else (including `-1`) is *truthy*.

Answer (score 3):

indexof() method returns the found text index. If it doesn't find anything, it returns -1.

You should change your code like this...

```
if (user.apilog[0].referer) {
    if (user.apilog[0].referer.indexOf('.google.') > -1)
        return  true
    else
        return false;
}
else {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test it:

```
if (-1) {
    console.log('true');
} 
else {
    console.log('false');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

-1 is estimated true in JavaScript.

For example:

```
var isTrue = -1;
if (isTrue) {
    console.log("TRUE");
}
else {
    console.log("FALSE");
}
```

will display TRUE.